# Read man page or file from certain row

Tags: linux, bash, unix, manpage

Is there a way to read a man page from a certain row?

I grepped for a specific flag in a man page and saw what line it was in, is there a way start reading the man form that line?

Answer (score 2):

`man`  uses $MANPAGER or $PAGER, so it depends on what you're using.  To start reading the manpage for `foo` at the first match of 'pattern', you might try:

```
MANPAGER='less -p pattern' man foo
```

or (assuming ${MANPAGER-PAGER} is `less`):

```
LESS+='-p pattern' man foo
```

Comment: Awesome solution, i'm still holding on accepting this as the answer to know if anyone else has some knowledge to share. thank you